# Как скрыть пункт меню в другом активити

Tags: android

Подскажите как можно скрыть один из пунктов меню в другом активити? А то сейчас этот пункт на всех активити. В методе onCreate написал следующее, но при переходе в активити программа вылетает.

```
MenuItem like = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.action_like);
        like.setVisible(false);
```

Вот стектрейс

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.MenuItem android.view.MenuItem.setVisible(boolean)' on a null object reference
>       at my.test.p1.ActivityAdd.onCreateOptionsMenu(ActivityAdd.java:121)
>       at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:3142)
>       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:362)
>       at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:92)
>       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:331)
>       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1357)
>       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1637)
>       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9$1.run(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:132)
>       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В методе onCreate() нельзя обращаться к меню, так как оно пока не создано. Используйте `onCreateOptionsMenu()`

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.tool_sort, menu);
MenuItem like = menu.findItem(R.id.action_like);
    like.setVisible(false);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Написал так. Вылетает все равно.

Comment: Прикрепите лог вылета (Стектрейс) в ваш вопрос.

Comment: прикрепил в своему вопросу

Comment: Судя по всему вы неправильный id элемента списка передаете если строка menu.findItem(R.id.action_like) вам возвращает null

Comment: Либо в строке getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.tool_sort, menu) вы передаете неправильный id  меню  и соответственно в нем нету елемента списка который вы ищете

Comment: id меню правильный, и id передаваемого пункта меню тоже.

Comment: Нашел, ошибку спасибо.